# Google Groups for Google Apps public subscribe page?

Tags: google-groups

I'll eventually get around to using the API, but for now all I want to do is have a link allowing the general public to sign up for our Google Apps account's Google Groups hosted e-newsletter. I've set "Allow email addresses outside of the domain to be added to this group and receive emails sent to this group." in the settings, but the URL provided for the group requires a login. What am I missing?